# Java List<String[]> Sorting

Tags: java

I have a Java List<String[]> of objects like ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],...

I need to sort this List by the way SQL does, i.e., Order by Column2, Column4. I have beat my head against this for a good while and appreciate help. I am thick headed on this and need a clear example.

Comment: Can you add an example how exactly it should work?

Comment: You need to write (or otherwise construct) a `Comparator<String[]>`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: so the arrays are always of the same length and there is no null values?

Comment: It smells like you should also do what SQL does and use a record type instead of an unstructured array.

Comment: The List<String[]> has object arrays that are 12 columns from a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<String[]> arraylistofStrings = loads1;
        Collections.sort(arraylistofStrings,new java.util.Comparator<String[]>() {
            public int compare(String[] strings, String[] otherStrings) {
                //First  followed by 2nd, 3rd and 4th
                String _temp1 = strings[0] + "_" + strings[1]+ "_" + strings[2]+ "_" + strings[3];
                String _temp2 = otherStrings[0] + "_" + otherStrings[1]+ "_" + otherStrings[2]+ "_" + otherStrings[3];

                return _temp1.compareTo(_temp2);
            }
        });


        for (String[] sa : arraylistofStrings) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sa));
        }
```

Comment: Another remote worker (like me) gave me a solution.